# Problem with normal derivative

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have a problem with normal derivative of given function $h(x)=e^{-ar^{2}}-e^{-ar^{2}_{0}}$ and showing that $L(h)>0$, where $L$ is elliptic operator. $L=\sum_{i,k}a_{ik}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}+\sum_{i}b_{i}(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \ (a_{ik},  b_i - \text{continuous})$

I found in the book that the normal derivative of $h$ is greater than $0$, but I don't know how to show that.

I did compute a gradient which is equal $-2ae^{-ar^{2}}\vec{x}$, so the normal derivative is $-2ae^{ar^{2}}\vec{x} \cdot \vec{n}$ and as I see $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{n}$ should be negative but I don't know why.

$L(h)=(\sum_{i,k}4a^2a_{ik}x_ix_k-\sum_{i}2ab_{i} x_i)e^{-ar^{2}}$

$L(h)$ should be greater than $0$, but why?

Comment: Should I understand that $r^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$? And $L = L(u)$ in the elliptic operator formula? And is $x$ in $b_i(x)$ a vector?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.

Comment: Then is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle#The_classical_strong_maximum_principle_for_linear_elliptic_PDE) perhaps a relevant reference?

Comment: There is nothing here about the normal derivative, and it is not shown why this is greater than 0 or am I missing something?

Comment: I still don't have a full understanding of the question. Where for example is the surface that's IMHO needed for the existence of a "normal"?

Comment: [proof](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-05/S0002-9939-1952-0050126-X/S0002-9939-1952-0050126-X.pdf)

Comment: Great! I will take a look at it as soon as I find time.

Comment: The [Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle#The_classical_strong_maximum_principle_for_linear_elliptic_PDE) I gave you __is__ relevant, because it is _following the original statement of Hopf (1927)_ in your [proof](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-05/S0002-9939-1952-0050126-X/S0002-9939-1952-0050126-X.pdf) But honestly, I still don't get it.

Comment: [What is a normal at the surface of a hypersphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144295/what-is-a-normal-at-the-surface-of-a-hypersphere)

Comment: Now I am a little confused. Why do we compute a normal vector to a hypersphere? It looks like the normal vector does not depend on the curve. I am right?

Comment: The hypersphere is mentioned in your "proof" reference. But I am very much confused myself too. I think it's wise to stop here; wait and see if someone else can offer some clarity in these matters.

Answer (score 1):

There is sloppyness in the question as well as in the
"[proof](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-05/S0002-9939-1952-0050126-X/S0002-9939-1952-0050126-X.pdf)"
mentioned in your comment.
But anyway, it's always wise to start with a special case if we can't cope immediately with the general problem.
So let's do the following.
$$
L(u) = a_{xx}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + a_{xy}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}
+ a_{yx}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x} + a_{yy}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} 
+ b_x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + b_y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
$$
Then we subsequently have:
$$
h(x,y) = e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}-e^{-a(x_0^2+y_0^2)} \\
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = -2ax\,e^{-a(x^2+y^2)} \quad ; \quad
\frac{\partial h}{\partial y} = -2ay\, e^{-a(x^2+y^2)} \quad \Longrightarrow \\
\vec{\nabla} h = -2a\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}
$$
A hypersphere in two dimensions is a circle; the normal to the "surface" of a circle is
$\,\vec{n}=\begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix}/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ; and so the inner product is
$$
(\vec{\nabla} h \cdot \vec{n}) =
-2a \begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix}/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}e^{-a(x^2+y^2)} =
 -2a\,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,e^{-a(x^2+y^2)} \lt 0
$$
Which is indeed negative instead of positive. Proceeding with the second order derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2} = \left[-2a + (-2ax)^2\right] e^{-a(x^2+y^2)} \\
\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y^2} = \left[-2a + (-2ay)^2\right] e^{-a(x^2+y^2)} \\
\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x \partial y} = (-2ax)(-2ay) e^{-a(x^2+y^2)} = \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y \partial y}
$$
And so for the "linear partial differential expression" we have:
$$
L(h) = \left[-2a(a_{xx}+a_{yy}+b_xx+b_yy) + 4a^2(a_{xx}x^2+a_{xy}xy+a_{yx}yx+a_{yy}y^2)\right]e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}
$$
Where it is noticed that there are additional terms for $x_i=x_k$ when compared with the analysis in your question.
But anyway, without additional resitrictions on $\,a_{ik}\,$ and $\,b_i\,$ it's difficult to see why $L(h)$ should be greater than $0$.

Hope this helps. To be honest, I do not understand the "proof" by [Eberhard Hopf](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberhard_Hopf) quite well.

EDIT.
The normal $\,\color{red}{\vec{n}}\,$ at a point of the surface of a hypersphere is the same as the vector towards that point $\,\vec{r}\,$,
apart from a norm. This is obvious for the two-dimensional hypersphere, called circle:

[image]

Comment: Well, the coefficient at $a^{2}$ is positive because the quadratic form is positive definite, but can not see why at $-2a$ is negative. I would be really grateful if you could tell me why a normal vector looks like that because I can not find any sources.

Comment: @KrzysztofB: Does my EDIT of the answer clarify something about the normal vector? However, you are absolutely right: I have yet to find a reference on the internet that justifies generalization of the circle and common sphere to an n-sphere.

Comment: @KrzysztofB: Okay, I see that the coefficient of $a^2$ is positive, but how about the term preceded by $(-2a)$? Doesn't that destroy the positiveness of $L(h)$?

Comment: In polar coordinates $\gamma (t)=[R \cos (t),R \sin (t)]=[\gamma _1, \gamma _2]$. I found that $\vec{N(t)}=\frac{[-\gamma _2'(t),\gamma _1'(t)]}{|\gamma '(t)|}=-\frac{[x,y]}{R}$. Where did I make mistake?

Comment: @KrzysztofB: Isn't the normal meant to be perpendicular to the __tangent__ at the circle?

Comment: Yes it is. In this example $\vec{T(t)}=\frac{[-R \sin (t),R \cos (t)]}{R}$ so $\vec{T(t)} \cdot \vec{N(t)} = 0$