# What is a normal at the surface of a hypersphere?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, spheres

Everything real-valued. Let $\vec{r} = (x,y)$ be the vector directed from the origin to a point at the perimeter of a circle.
Then the normal perpendicular to that perimeter at that point is $\vec{n} = \vec{r}/|\vec{r}|$.

[image]

In very much the same way, the normal at the *surface* of a sphere is $\vec{n} = \vec{r}/|\vec{r}|$ with $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$.

Question is: how is a normal at the surface of a hypersphere in n-dimensional space defined?
I would say, analogously to the
sphere and the circle, as follows:
$$
\vec{r} = (x_1,x_2,x_3, \cdots , x_n) \quad ; \quad \vec{n} = \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|}
$$
But I haven't seen such a definition anywhere on the internet, for example with
[N sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) , [Unit sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere) ,
[Hypersphere](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html) .

Anyway, what **is** the surface of a hypersphere and how is a (normed) vector perpendicular to it defined?

**Note.** Motivated by a question elsewhere at MSE:
[Problem with normal derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4138973/problem-with-normal-derivative).

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)#Hypersurfaces_in_n-dimensional_space

Comment: @HandeBruijn As the other comment indicates, we can find the normal vector using the gradient of the function whose level set defines the surface. We indeed find that the normal vector is equal to $\vec n = \frac{\vec r}{|\vec r|}$, as you have guessed.

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. I should have known this, but my knowledge has become a bit rusty :-( Thanks.

Comment: @BenGrossmann. Thanks to both comments I can now formulate my own (very simple) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)#Hypersurfaces_in_n-dimensional_space),
and as formulated in the comment by Ben Grossmann, *we can find the normal vector using the gradient of the function whose level set defines the surface*.

For a hypersphere with radius $R$ that is:
$$
F(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) = \left|\vec{r}\right|^2-R^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 - R^2 = 0
$$
And so, apart from a norming factor:
$$
\vec{n} =
\vec{\nabla} F = \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2},\cdots,\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_n}\right) =
2\left(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\right) = 2\,\vec{r}
$$